# How to prevent default when click on icon inside a anchor link list?

Tags: jquery

I have a link list with namnes that loads a new page if you click on the li.

And besides the name I have a heart icon.

And when I click on the heart I want to prevent the default behavior on the link and just open an alert instead(not loading the page).
And if I click anywhere else on the li then it should load the page as expected.

I have this structure now.

```
<a href="page.html">  
    <li>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">Anna Andersson</div>
          <div class="item-after">

        <i class="f7-icons fodelsedag">heart_fill</i>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
    </a>
```

And here is the js code.

```
$$(document).on('click', '.fodelsedag', function (e) { 

//so how can I prevent the default on the li here?
alert("test alert")


});
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You need to stop the event bubbling, not prevent its action. Use `e.stopPropagation()`. Note that your HTML is invalid, though as the implication here is that the `a` is a child of a `ul` or `ol`, which is not allowed as only `li` can be in that position.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I use framework7 so the structure has to be like that on the list. I tested to put e.stopPropagation() inside the click function but and it shows the alert, but still navigates to the page. So it seams like it does´t work.

Comment: So once the alert is open, you want to make page clickable then ?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to click on the li and go to the page when I have closed the alert.

Comment: The question is actually unclear, it seems like you do NOT want to redirect if you click the `heart_fill` element? Is that wrong?
Do you want the page to always redirect regardless of where is clicked, but if clicking the `heart_fill` it shows an alert first? If so, the browser will always block a redirect if an alert is on the page until it is dismissed.
You will see my answer does not redirect user after dismissing the alert, and the alert is only shown when clicking the `heart_fill` element

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change your markup so it is valid. `li` must be the direct descendant of your `ol` or `ul` element, you will need your `a` tag inside the `li` element:

```
<ul><li>  
 <a href="page.html" class="link">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-title">Anna Andersson</div>
      <div class="item-after">
        <i class="f7-icons fodelsedag">heart_fill</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and then your script needs to prevent bubbling:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('fodelsedag')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    alert("test alert");
});
```

Comment: preventPropagation is not  a method.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `stopPropagation`, not `preventPropogation`. I have corrected my answer. Here is reference to propagation in the jQuery library - https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: How will anything else work if the alert is open ? The econd requirement of OP is not met.

Comment: It did, the second script block should be used. I have removed the OP's original script block for clarity

Comment: I have updated the code to fully address the OP requirement of the child element not allowing the page to continue to redirect @rach8garg